# state is not updating?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I click on my calculator buttons 1-9 it will only change the display input for a split second and go back to its default value. For example if I click on the 1 button it will display 1 in the input for second and then go back to a blank input.

This is my first time using React besides going through it in code academy

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Display} from "./Display";
import {Button} from "./Button"
import {Functionality} from "./Functionality.js"
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {value: ""}
    this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);
  }
  
  handle(event) {
    
    
    this.setState({value: event})
    //this.componentDidMount(this.setState({value: event.target.value }))
    alert(event)
    
  }
  
  

  render(){
    var calcContainer = (
    
      <div className="container">
        
        <Display value={this.state.value} />
  
        <form className="buttons">
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "1"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "2"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "3"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "4"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "5"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "6"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "7"/>
          <Button onClick={this.handle} value = "8"/>
          <Button value = "9"/>
          <Button onClear={this.clear} id="clear" value = "clear"/>
          <Button id="submit" value = "submit"/>
          <Button id="+" value = "+"/>
          
        </form>
        
      </div>
      
  
    )
    return calcContainer;
    
  }
}
export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App.js';


export class Button extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }
    
    handleChange(e) {
        //alert("kkk")
        e.persist()
        var buttonValue = e.target.value;
        //alert(buttonValue)
        //alert(this.props.onClick(buttonValue))
        //alert(this.props.handle(buttonValue))
        this.props.onClick(buttonValue);
        
        
      }
    render(){
       return (
            <button onClick={this.handleChange} 
                className="button_number"
                 value =  {this.props.value}
                 //input = "2"
                >
                 
               {this.props.value}
            </button>
       )
    }
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom";

export class Display extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    
    render(){
        return( 
        <div classname="container">
            <input  type="text" value={this.props.value} />
            
        </div>)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have everything wrapped in a `<form>`, when you click one of the `<button>` elements, the form gets "submitted" -- it has nowhere to go, so the page just ends up refreshing.

To prevent this, you can add `e.preventDefault()` in the `handleChange` method of your `Button` class.

Another option would be not using the `<form>` wrapper.